# Determine Probability of Numbers Within a Set, Uniformly Distributed, to Sum to a Number

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a set of numbers, for example (0,2,3,4,5,6), each with even distribution. I want to know what the chances are that some number of them (X) will add up to Y or greater. What would that formula look like?

Comment: Are you allowing repetition?

Comment: Yes. Repitition is permitted.

Comment: If by 'formula' you mean a 'clean' closed-form like say for the binomial distribtion, I don't think you'll find there is one for this problem. You'll need to enumerate the possibilities, and use whatever restriction (e.g. 'adds to 6') to get the probabilities. Do you know about convolution? If so, representing the numbers as a list and convolving it the $X$ times gets you the probabilities of all possible combinations from which you can pull out those that meet the criteria (like 'adds to 6 or more'. You can also use the multinomial distribution to get the probabilities of the combinations.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your set is $A = \{a_i, i=1\ldots n\}$, where all $a_i$ are nonnegative integers.  Let $X$ be a random choice from $S$.  Then the probability generating function of $X$ is $g(z) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n z^{a_i}$ which is a polynomial.  If $X_1, \ldots, X_m$ are independent with the same distribution,
the probability generating function of $S = X_1 + \ldots + X_m$ is 
$g_m(z) = g(z)^m$.  Then $$P(S \ge y) = \sum_{j=y}^\infty g_m^{(j)}(0)/j! = 1 - \sum_{j=0}^{y-1} g_m^{(j)}(0)/j!$$

Comment: Many thanks. I think that will do it.